# Window phone 8.1 app certification fails due to SQLite

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, sqlite-net, app-certification-kit

Windows phone 8.1 app certification fails due the following error
Which is something like this but very big one

> This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=sqlite3_aggregate_context. Module=sqlite3.dll.
>   File=SQLitePCL.raw.dll. This API is not supported for this application
>   type - Api=sqlite3_aggregate_count. Module=sqlite3.dll.
>   File=SQLitePCL.raw.dll. This API is not supported for this application
>   type - Api=sqlite3_backup_finish. Module=sqlite3.dll.
>   File=SQLitePCL.raw.dll.

Please help me fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added reference to SQLite for Windows phone 8.1 and it passed the app certification.